# std::move items out of an STL container?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move-semantics

I'm trying to `std::move` an element out of a `std::set` and then erase it from the set:

```
std::set<some_type> the_set;
some_type item;   

for (auto iter = the_set.begin(); iter != the_set.end(); iter++)
{
    auto miter = std::make_move_iterator(iter);
    item = std::move(*miter);
    the_set.erase(iter);
    break;
}
```

The compiler doesn't like it, though (MSVC 2015):

```
error C2280: 'some_type &some_type::operator =(const some_type &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Seems like it's trying to use a copy constructor instead, which I don't want.  How would I get it to use the move constructor?  (I tried the `move_iterator` out of desperation, not sure if it's the right solution here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set` iterators are effectively `const` iterators (in C++11 and later). That way, you cannot possibly change them and break `set`'s ordering.

And you cannot move from a `const&&`. So you cannot move out of a `set`.

C++17 will permit you to do so, but [via a different API (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf). Basically, you have to [extract the node itself from the `set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract), then move the object in the node, and then destroy the node (by letting it fall off the stack). I believe the code would look something like this:

```
for (auto iter = the_set.begin(); iter != the_set.end(); iter++)
{
    auto node = the_set.extract(iter);
    item = std::move(node.value());
    break;
}
```

Comment: Since in my case I'm deleting right after moving, could I use const cast to accomplish the move?  I know it's probably a bit hacky...

Comment: @atanamir: Probably not. The moment you `move` it out (and something actually mutates its contents to swap data), the `set` is in inconsistent state (the sort invariant is likely broken). The algorithms it would use to remove the item rely on this invariant (heck, they rely on the object being in a usable state for stuff like `operator<` calls, and the only guarantee you get after you've moved out of something is that it's possible to reassign or destroy it, nothing else is allowed; it might have `NULL` pointers that are illegal otherwise). Don't try to do this.

Comment: @atanamir: That said, looks like C++17 is introducing [`std::set::extract`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) that would allow what you're trying to do (assuming I'm reading it right).